# Multilingual App Toolkit no longer builds, XLIFF validation failed, "trans-unit" has invalid child element

Tags: multilingual-app-toolkit

I just started getting build errors with the Multilingual App Toolkit (in VS 2019). It was working fine a couple months ago, nothing on my machine changed.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The XLIFF file failed validation on line 0, Position 0. Message 'The element 'trans-unit' in namespace 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2' has invalid child element 'target' in namespace 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2'. List of possible elements expected: 'context-group, count-group, prop-group, note, alt-trans' in namespace 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2' as well as any element in namespace '##other'.'. PowerPlannerAppDataLibrary  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Multilingual App Toolkit\v4.0\Microsoft.Multilingual.ResxResources.targets 32
```

It seems some XSD file has gone missing...

[image]

Comment: I am trying to solve this issue. Did you find anything helpful?

Comment: Hey Jan, I think this error was maybe caused by having Arabic translations (maybe there was an invalid character or something). I never really figured it out though, instead I built my own localization tool that takes the XLIFF files and generates RESXs from them. It's open source and on NuGet: https://github.com/barebonesdev/xliff-compiler Limited instructions, but used in my open source proj here: https://github.com/powerplanner/powerplannerapps/tree/master/PowerPlannerAppDataLibrary Good luck!